# Separate or anonymize activity on separate stackexchange sites without inconvenient multiple logins

Tags: discussion, feature-request, linked-accounts, social-networking

The stackexchange unified system works pretty well.  You can check all site activity through one simple interface, and everything is neatly tied together.

Which is great.

Except.

Except when your "hobby" sites (parenting.stackexchange.com, gaming.stackexchange.com, one of the religion.se.com sites, skeptics.se, whatever it is) **may reveal too much about you**.  Employers can conceivably *use personal information to bias their hiring*.  This is **Not Good**™.

I'll post a solution I have for this below.

Comment: Wait a minute, if I change my user id on one stackexchange site (I've never done that before), will it change it everywhere else? I'm not sure about that.

Comment: similar (not exactly the same) request for [witness protection program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witness_Protection_Program "what's this?") is currently discussed at Workplace Meta: [Can you add an ask anonymously feature for stack exchanges like this and onstartups?](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/395/168)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to solve this is to give people the option to create a "proxy" account on certain sites.

[image: john_doe]

Here `john_doe` is using his natural_id (as `john_doe`) everywhere except on skeptics.se.